# How to check what version of USB connection a keyboard has?

Tags: keyboard

I'm about to get Lenovo Preferred Pro keyboard because I wanted something cheap and at the same time good quality, so it seems Preferred Pro is the best for that price. Anyways, how do I check what version of USB it is?

Comment: In most cases it shouldn't matter. USB keyboards won't use/need the full bandwidth of USB 2.0.

Comment: Most keyboards these days are 2.0. check with the vendor, it really doesn't matter. Even if it was USB 1.1 or something it really wouldn't matter, its just a keyboard, you're not going to use it as a USB hub are you?

Comment: Before you buy it? Ask the manufacturer, check spec and/or data sheets, etc. That said, it's a keyboard, so it'd seem to be *likely* to be USB 1.1 because it really doesn't need to be anything more than that. It certainly should be USB 1.1 compatible, meaning it'll work on near *anything* that has USB HID input support.

Comment: I'm interested in what difference you think the USB version makes. It's likely based on a misunderstanding of some kind, for example that a USB hub downgrades the speed of all ports to the lowest speed.

Comment: This questions reads like a plug for Lenovo Preferred Pro keyboards! Until reading this question, I didn't even know they represented quality and at a cheap price, that *is* hard to beat I guess!

Comment: Well, I will use whatever is faster and more responsive for sure. I will use it for gaming too, so isn't that important? Is using a PS/2 adapter going to make it faster/more responsive?

Comment: @evil even gaming, I'd be very impressed if your fingers can type more than 12 MBits of data per second, which is what full speed USB 1 can transfer.

Comment: I suspect if you typed that fat you're wear your fingers to the bone, or set the keyboard on fire.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually written an [article](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/08/01/keyboard-capersa-field-guide-to-keyboards/) for this for the SU blog in the past

I guess what you're *really* asking is what interface it uses and what advantages it may have.

Firstly a lot of keyboards do *both* PS/2 and USB with a simple, passive converter, so your keyboard may be both. The internal circuitry is roughly the same so there's little difference - keyboards have negligible latency compatred to human reaction times. There's no real practical advantage to USB 2.0 or 3.0 for most HID applications so this shouldn't matter.

Practically speaking the big advantage that PS/2 keyboards are supposed to have over USB keyboards is something called NKRO - the ability to press more than a certain number of keys at once. Unless you're already having issues with it , this may not be an issue.

The choice of switch type on the other hand may make some difference - I prefer mechanical keyboards, but a good scissor switch type keyboard might be a lot better than a standard membrane switch keyboard.

So... no, using PS/2 or USB shouldn't make a difference. Getting a keyboard you're comfortable with and fits well does.

Comment: Thanks. I'm saving for a Filco Majestouch 2, as I found out (well, a lot of praise from a lot of people overall) it is the best thing, or one of the best when it comes to mechanical keyboards. But it's pricey, so I need something to use until I get the Filco. I know that nothing beats the mechanical keyboard.



Slightly off topic, but do you think there's better quality keyboard for that price than the Lenovo? I need standard/traditional layout. All Logitech ones are not traditional...

Comment: There's a secondary advantage of PS/2: it generates hardware interrupts instead of polling, so can be more 'responsive' (lower latencies). However, you are really unlikely to notice, unless the system is under a *lot* of high-priority load.

Comment: The logitech bundles are - used one for ages before I got my mechanical. They're alright, and fairly cheap

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment to the original question, I will answer a slightly different question, regarding responsiveness and latency.

USB version is not going to make a squat difference for keyboard responsiveness. The data packets are so small that the difference is negligible. What might make a small difference is the poll rate for HID devices. In USB, devices can't end an interrupt to the host. Instead, the hot must periodically poll the device for changes, which can be done up to 1000 Hz. (That is, 1000 times per second.)

By default in Windows, the poll rate is 125 Hz, which means this stage will potentially introduce 8 milliseconds in the input->output latency chain. 125 Hz means that the USB keyboard is polled slightly more often than two times per frame, at a screen refresh of 60 Hz. (The 60 Hz screen refresh will introduce up to 16.7 ms latency, which is the time it takes for on frame to be transferred.) This was deemed satisfactory for general use. In the worst case scenario, this 8 ms latency will cause you to miss the rendering of one frame, causing a cumulative latency `8+16.7+x ms`, or `24.7+x ms,` where `x` is all other latency in the chain, like the time it takes for the game to process and render the frame, and the latency introduced by some monitors because they're buffering the . (This is likely to be the dominant time term.)

If you still want to optimize this latency, you can use the hidusbf utility, linked below. However, be aware that it's a bit fiddly to set up, especially on 64-bit operating systems.

http://www.ngohq.com/news/15043-how-to-increase-usb-sample-rate-in-windows-vista-7-a.html